# What is this specific newspaper section called in English?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

In France, in local newspapers (mostly small town magazines), there is sometimes a section called "État civil" ("civil register"), where you can find the names of the people who married, have born and died in the town during the last month/week/semester.

How is this specific newspaper section called in English, supposing it's not just a french thing? I couldn't find anything certain by searching online dictionaries and Google.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a thing in English speaking newspapers too, at least it was while newspapers were still relevant, especially at the local level. I believe the section was called *Announcements*, but I'll go google to confirm.

Comment: It is colloquially known as "*Hatches, Matches and Dispatches*"

Comment: In the US, something like "Legal and Public Notices", though it has been some time since l last read a print newspaper. But I think if you check a print newspaper's online edition you should find such a section.

Answer (score 1):

Per New York Times, Washington Post:

Marriages: ["Wedding Announcements"](https://www.nytimes.com/spotlight/wedding-announcements) (or "Marriage Announcements")
Deaths: ["Obituaries"](https://www.nytimes.com/section/obituaries)
Births: ["Birth Announcements"](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/local/2002/02/21/birth-announcements/f31d9792-e5c1-4f2e-8c52-50541b347341/?utm_term=.775c8f574855)